# Prevent PayPal Payments with payKey (Or refund instead)

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to prevent paypal for allowing a payment I have created.

The scenario:
My App is creating a Payment. I get the payKey from PayPal and the Customer is redirected to PayPal. 
When the Customer is not able to finish the Payment after 2 minutes I will delete the Order for him and then - if possible - I will force Paypal that the payment is not active anymore and the customer is not able to pay after these 2 minutes. For this I have to do at least of this:

- send Paypal the payKey and tell Paypal: Do not allow to pay with this payKey! Just "Delete" the information for this order
- after the customer paid - but after 2 minutes, so the order is deleted - I will tell Paypal the payKey and a refund has to be done right after the customer has paid. This is no problem I thought but because its an AdaptivePayment and chained paypal is not allowing me to refund the money because every receiver in the refund receiverList needs permissions to allow a refund by API Call.

So my question is:
Is it possible to prevent a Payment with an API call ? I did not find any information in the REST API Reference of PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

The payKey cannot be deleted or change the expire duration. You can use [delayed chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/) with [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). You are the API caller and primary receiver, compare the transaction complete time with the paykey generation time to decide refund or pay secondary receivers.